# Cordova ionic can't connect to to any internet services

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been building an app with cordova and ionic using angular js. When I complile the project to android everything works fine, but with iOS I can't connect to anything.

I'm trying to log in to firebase database, as well as exchange some HTTP requests. again, all works fine on android.

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="private.private.private" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Puurs 725</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*youtube.com" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.lotsofprivatenumbers" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Fun thing is that this was supposed to be working. But I accidently overwrote my index.html file. In there meta data for my index I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Rings a bell to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learned how to hook up my ipad running the app to my mac, debugged the safari console (this feature is awesome) and found out a javascript error was blocking further executions.

More specific, Object.values is not supported on safari.